# Error when personalizing JSS renderings

Tags: jss, personalization

I'm getting the following error when I try to personalize a JSS component that was deployed into a `JSS tenant on 9.2`:

```
> Cannot read property 'image' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined
   at DemoSimplePromo (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc92sc.dev.local\dist\react-with-sitecore\server.bundle.js:26682:25)
   at c (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc92sc.dev.local\dist\react-with-sitecore\server.bundle.js:12516:496)
   at Ga (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc92sc.dev.local\dist\react-with-sitecore\server.bundle.js:12519:1)
   at a.render (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc92sc.dev.local\dist\react-with-sitecore\server.bundle.js:12524:367)
   at a.read (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc92sc.dev.local\dist\react-with-sitecore\server.bundle.js:12523:450)
   at renderToString (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc92sc.dev.local\dist\react-with-sitecore\server.bundle.js:12535:82)
   at process (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc92sc.dev.local\dist\react-with-sitecore\server.bundle.js:16563:20)
   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
```

Note that `image` is a field on the template that was created from the component definition, as part of the deployment.

```
export default function(manifest) {
manifest.addComponent({
name: 'Demo-SimplePromo',
icon: SitecoreIcon.Target,
fields: [
  { name: 'heading', type: CommonFieldTypes.SingleLineText },
  { name: 'content', type: CommonFieldTypes.RichText },
  { name: 'image', type: CommonFieldTypes.Image},
  { name: 'link', type: CommonFieldTypes.GeneralLink}
]
```

All I did was add a `where true` condition to the rendering in `Experience Editor`. I tried pointing it to a new data source (created by duplicating the data source item created by the deploy script), but I also tried just setting the personalized data source to the same item as the default.

Comment: can you please try with renaming the "image" field to like "xyzimageabc".

Comment: Please try to implement the personalization in the sample app and verify that its issue with Sitecore environment or Custom Component developed by you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Amit Kumar. However, the same error happens when I personalize one of the "Content Data" examples int he Styleguide. (Error Rendering Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JsLayoutRenderer: Cannot read property 'sample' of undefined)